# Tensorflow: best way to vertically stack matrices?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let say I have a 3D tensor representing several 2D matrices:

```
3D_tensor = tf.random_uniform([N0, N1, N2], 1, -1))
```

I want to stack vertically these 2D matrices such that the resulting 2D tensor would be of dimensions [N0+N1, N2]. WHat is the best way to do that ?

The numpy process would be the following one:

```
3D = np.array([ [[1,2],[3,4]] , [[1,2],[3,4]] ]) # 3D.shape = (2,2,2)
2D = np.vstack(3D) # D2.shape = (4,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape:

```
import tensorflow as tf

D3 = tf.constant([ [[1,2],[3,4]] , [[1,2],[3,4]] ])
D2 = tf.reshape(D3, shape=(4,2))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(D2.eval())
```

gives

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

which corresponds to your numpy example.

Alternatively, you can `split`, then `concat`:

```
D3_split = tf.split(D3, axis=-1, num_or_size_splits=2)
D2_bis = tf.squeeze(tf.concat(D3_split, axis=0))
```